# How to invoke newly added system call by the function id without using syscall(__NR_mysyscall)

Tags: linux, operating-system, system-calls

I am working with Linux-3.9.3 kernel in Ubuntu 10.04. I have added a basic system call in the kernel directory of the linux-3.9.3 source tree. I am able to use it with `syscall()` by passing my newly system call number in it as an argument. But I want to invoke it directly by using its method name as in the case of `getpid()` or `open()` system calls. Can any one help me to add it in GNU C library. I went through few documents but did not get any clear idea of how to accomplish it.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Notice that C does not have "method names" only "function names"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on a 64 bits Linux [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64), the relevant [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) is the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf). Read also the [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) wikipage and the [linux assembly howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

So [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) are using a different convention than ordinary function calls (e.g. all arguments are passed by registers, error condition could use the carry bit). Hence, you need a C wrapper to make your syscall available to C applications.

You could look into the source code of existing C libraries, like [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html) or [musl libc](http://www.musl-libc.org) (so you'll need to make your own library for that syscall).
The *MUSL libc* source code is very readable, see e.g. its [src/unistd/fsync.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/unistd/fsync.c) as an example.

I would suggest wrapping your new syscall in your own library without patching `libc`. Notice that some uncommon syscalls are sitting in a different library, e.g. [request_key(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/request_key.2.html) has its C wrapper in `libkeyutils`